# Spotify desktop app is developed with javascript?

Tags: javascript, desktop, spotify

I have used Spotify for some time now and I thought it was a 100% native desktop app til I saw a HTTP request error inside the application.

So that makes me wondering if Spotify is developed with javascript using frameworks like Titanium.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses a web browser component for certain portions (content areas), many larger apps with dynamic content do this...but it is a native app, not written completely in JavaScript.

Doing it this way provides more flexibility and ability to make changes without a client code update.

Comment: Do you have more information about how to create this javascript component?

Comment: @ajsie - It's not a JavaScript component really, it's a browser component, many frameworks have one...they're basically just loading a small webpage.

Answer (score 6):

Spotify uses [chromium embedded](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/). So actually the Spotify desktop application wraps a chrome browser so to say.

Comment: Now I know why it shows the same jumpy erratic scrolling behavior like my chrome browser in conjunction with a Logitech mouse.

Answer (score 3):

This question was answered here [community.spotify](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/Chromium-Embedded-Framework/td-p/912377)

It uses [chromium embedded framework](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/)

Answer (score 1):

See [spotifyonline.co.nr](http://spotifyonline.co.nr) if you want something like this . :)

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore. Does anyone know of a new location for this?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not developed in Javascript, it uses an internal html-like (but not so like) framework for the web content, and its proprietary, probably because it tightly integrated with the content backend, which is proprietary due to legal rights.

Comment: it's very html like. as in the apps are html+javascript rendered with chrome's engine. the difference to normal chrome is that it has extra api's for controlling spotify playback and for making search queries etc.